# How to auto-complete an object instantiation in Android Studio?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

For example, when I type `ArrayList<String> data =`, how can I auto-complete this so that it shows `ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();`?

PS: I do remember there is a way to do so in eclipse, but I don't know how to do it in android studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `Object obj = new` and then

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space bar</kbd>

Example:

```
String str = new (ctrl+shift+space)
```

will give you

```
String str = new String();
```

For Objects that have paramters it will show suggestion as in while creating Collection objects like `List<E>` and `ArrayList<E>` like,

[image: Android studio ArrayList autocomplete screen capture!]

*Reference:* [Here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) is a full list of Key map for Windows

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the default keymap, it's Ctrl + Shift + A

Reference: 
https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/index.jsp

Comment: this seems not work for my case. it just pops up a search box and asks me to enter some action.

Comment: Try changing the keymap to default, as the first document suggests?